# SSRS report multi select parameter does not select values automatically

Tags: reporting-services

In SSRS report I have 2 parameters ClassName and StudentName both are allow to select multiple values. StudentName parameter react according to ClassName parameter's value. Both parameters have default values. when I run the report default value selected in ClassName dropdown and as per ClassName value StudentName values selected by default in StudentName dropdown as per below image.

[image]

Now, When I select more than one values from ClassName as per below image I can retrieve correct student names in StudentName dropdown but values are not selected by default.

[image]

Expected result should be as below:

[image]

is this SSRS limitation? or is there any work around?

Comment: How are you selecting your Default Values for your Student parameter? You should be using the same as the Available Values since you want them all. Your query should reference the Class parameter - **Select Student from STUDENTS WHERE CLASS IN (@CLASS)**

Comment: Seems that's the default behaviour for SSRS cascading parameters. It auto selects all StudentName values only for the first time it get's values for the ClassName parameter. Each other time user has to make a select all. See if it's better initialy to leave ClassName parameter with no default values.

Comment: @HannoverFist I am using same dataset (select studentname from Table_3 where classname in (@ClassName) ) for default values as well as available values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modified StudentName dataset as below:

```
SELECT S.StudentName + '_' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY S.StudentName ASC) AS VARCHAR(50)) AS studentname1,
       S.StudentName
FROM
(SELECT StudentName FROM Table_3 WHERE ClassName IN ( @ClassName )) S;
```

And modified Value field to studentname1 for @StudentName parameter in available values and default values.

Comment: Good job. I forgot about the Default value not refreshing issue.

Comment: hi Jay, I have exactly the same problem. I am not sure how you fixed it. Can you please explain it a little bit more.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to this issue is to change the default options(student name) every time and in some way dependent on changed parameter(className).
 Like in your report student names are default options and remains same(Smith or Jack) for any class input and new options not getting select. 
earlier my values were Student1 [result on first change of date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MX4hx.png)
later I add date to me student like Student1_2124 (2124 is Julian Date and dependes on Date parameter) It will change the Student everytime so result is all selected values [new all selected parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJZh7.png)

all options would be selected only if you can make student name like  Jack_className and use only before underscore to print in report.
It worked for me.